# Show specific data from excel to specific user in sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have an excel sheet where there are two columns:

1. Email
2. loyalty points

example:

| Email | Loyalty Points |
| --- | --- |
| abc1@company.com | 248 |
| abc2@company.com | 540 |

My requirement:

When a user (**abc1@company.com**) login to his SharePoint he should see the token value as 248 and when the user (**abc2@company.com**) login to SharePoint then he should see the token value as 540.

Till now I have created a page on sharepoint and now I am wondering how to load data specific to user and display it in the sharepoint page.

Answer (score 0):

Solution might be to Import That excel to a SharePoint list. Now based on situations:

**A) Unique Item Permission**

You can set unique permission per item in the SP library, then set it only for managers group and specific user.
Set unique item permission part can be automatized with WF or Power Automate Flow as well, after that it can be done for large amount of items (limit for unique item permission in SP list is 50 000)

**B) View with filter**

If the Loyalty Points are not secret and you just dont want to spam users with a lot of rows....you can create a list view in SharePoint list...Where you limit the values with Filter. `(Library settings > Views > Create View)` in Filter part you select person/group Column "Email" and in value you can put `[Me]`

> [Me] and [today] are only available dynamic filters in View settings

You can display this view on HomePage for example and it will show always values only for specific user.